# Using FFT transformation with AudioRecord

Tags: android, audio, fft, audiorecord

I was following this example to transform to FFT http://som-itsolutions.blogspot.com.ee/2012/01/fft-based-simple-spectrum-analyzer.html. I have gotten it running but the results I get are pretty wierd. If I use the transofrmer (from FFT class), all I get are 0.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.kaka);

    int bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(frequency,
            channelConfiguration, audioEncoding);
    audioRecord = new AudioRecord(
            MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT, frequency,
            channelConfiguration, audioEncoding, bufferSize);

    buffer = new short[blockSize];
    toTransform = new double[blockSize];
    try {
        audioRecord.startRecording();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        Log.e("Recording failed", e.toString());

    }
    transformer = new RealDoubleFFT(blockSize);

    final Runnable r = new Runnable() {

        public void run() {

            Log.d("Amplify","HERE");
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Working!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    audioRecord.read(buffer, 0, blockSize);
                    for (int i = 0; i < blockSize && i < bufferReadResult; i++) {
                        toTransform[i] = (double) buffer[i] / 32768.0; // signed 16 bit
                    }
                    transformer.ft(toTransform);
                    text.setText("result:" + toTransform[10]);
                    handler.postDelayed(this, 150); // amount of delay between every cycle of volume level detection
                }
            });

        }
    };
    handler.postDelayed(r, 80);
```

I also saw a code where it said that you had to implement the code from the link I first provided and add this method to calculate it:

```
public static int calculate(int sampleRate, short [] audioData){
    int numSamples = audioData.length;
    int numCrossing = 0;
    for (int p = 0; p < numSamples-1; p++)
    {
        if ((audioData[p] > 0 && audioData[p + 1] <= 0) ||
                (audioData[p] < 0 && audioData[p + 1] >= 0))
        {
            numCrossing++;
        }
    }

    float numSecondsRecorded = (float)numSamples/(float)sampleRate;
    float numCycles = numCrossing/2;
    float frequency = numCycles/numSecondsRecorded;

    return (int)frequency;
}
```

The method calculate takes 2 parameters, first of which is samplerate but the other one is short[] audiodata. I tried giving the "buffer" as the variable but the results I got were nowhere near what was to be expected.

Is there anyone who is familiar with this example or can someone explain to me how can i get data from: audiorecord.read(...). I understand the part where you set the audiorecord to record the input, but when what exactly happens when you .read the data is what I did not understand.

It would be really hard to involve all of the FFT transformation classes, but here is the .ft that is used in this example:

```
  public void ft(double x[]){
     if(x.length != ndim)
          throw new IllegalArgumentException("The length of data can not match that of the wavetable");
     rfftf(ndim, x, wavetable);
  }
```

I understand that this must be confusing so I'll try to sum it up, my questions are:

What output does audiorecord.read(..) give and how can I use it?

If I were to use the calculate method then what is the input expected there?

The FFT transform gives me an array with length of 2048 and all of the ints inside are 0.00, what should I do?

Maybe I am doing it completely the wrong way and I don't need to use FFT to get the frequency from user input. But as a result I don't need to draw a graph I just need to move an image accordingly to the frequency change (higher/lower).

Answer (score 0):

A few things come to mind...

Is audio record allowed in manifest file?

Audiorecord.read appears to only run once? This should be enclosed in a while() statement. if its capturing 256 bytes at a time it will probably need to run over and over

It would be easier for you to put this entire code block into an async task and publish progress back to the UI. Check out my example below. The only difference is I am using bytes instead of shorts

```
 @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(File... files) {

        try {
        waveOut = new FileOutputStream(files[0]);


        int minBufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(SAMPLE_RATE, CHANNEL_MASK, ENCODING);
        audioRecord = new AudioRecord(AUDIO_SOURCE, SAMPLE_RATE, CHANNEL_MASK, ENCODING, minBufferSize);


            writeWavHeader(waveOut,CHANNEL_MASK,SAMPLE_RATE,ENCODING);

        int bufferReadData;
        byte[] buffer1 = new byte[blockSize * 2];
        long total = 0;

        try{
            startTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
            audioRecord.startRecording();

        }catch (IllegalStateException e){

            Log.e(TAG, " Records doInBackground: " + e.toString() );
        }



        while(running)
        {


            bufferReadData = audioRecord.read(buffer1,0,blockSize);  //we are requesting 256 byte obj and android is sending us 16bit so each byte hold half of a 16 bit!!


           createFFT(bufferReadData,buffer1);



            createWavFile(total,bufferReadData,buffer1);


        }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Records doInBackground: " + e.toString(), e);
            stoprecording();
        } finally {

            Log.i(TAG, "Records doInBackground: calld from 2nd");

                endTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();

        }

        try {
        updateWavHeader(files[0]);}catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "doInBackground: ", e);
        }

        return false;
    }





  protected void createFFT(int bufferReadData, byte[] buffer1)
    {
        double[] toTransform = new double[blockSize/2];

        //ByteBuffer.wrap(buffer1).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).asShortBuffer().put(buffer);   //this hopefully creates the buffer1 array

        // xx is correct bits. Here we load byte from buffer lilendian to big to feed into the newBuff
        //  xx xx xx xx 00 00 00 00
        //  00 00 00 00 xx xx xx xx
        //  xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx
        // 0xFF added to fix a left padding problem??

        short newBuff, buffLil, buffBig, count = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < blockSize/2 && i < bufferReadData/2; i++) //after 128 runs with a double increment it is pulling what data?
        {

            buffLil = buffer1[count];
            buffBig = buffer1[count + 1];
            newBuff = (short) ( buffBig <<8 | buffLil & 0xFF);
            count ++;
            count++;
            toTransform[i] = (double) newBuff / 32768.0;             //This takes the short and divides by total short value to give a decimal double value between -1.0 to 1.0 for input into fft
        }

        transformer.ft(toTransform);

        String w = String.valueOf(toTransform.length);
        //String w = String.valueOf(toTransform[0]);
        Log.i(TAG, "createFFT: " + w);

        publishProgress(toTransform);





    }



   @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(double[]...toTransform){



        uiChartBuffer = toTransform;




     }
```